# mail(/home/xxxxx/.logs/mail.log): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Tags: php, html

Estoy tratando de enviar emails a correos de gmail, con anterioridad si los enviaba sin ningun problema, pero ahora me empezó a salir este error:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  mail(/home/uXXXX/.logs/mail.log): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>/home/uXXXXX/domains/XXXXXX.com/public_html/lib/ADMIN/UP/class/Estudiante.php</b> on line <b>4278</b><br />
```

El codigo que se encarga de enviar el email:

```
public function email(){
    $email  = $this->_email;
    $password =$this->_rollNo;
    $message= "¡Te damos la más calida bienvenida!.";
    $subject= "Bienvenido";
    $anio= date("Y"); 
    ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
  error_reporting( E_ALL );
    $htmlContent= 'Aqui va el documento HTML';
    
    // Establecer encabezado de tipo de contenido para enviar Email HTML
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    
    // Encabezados adicionales
    
    
    $tipo_correo =explode('@',$email);
    if ($tipo_correo['1']=='gmail.com'){
    
    // Cabeceras adicionales para gmail
    $headers .= "From: XXX@XXXX.com";
}   
else {
    // Cabeceras adicionales para hotmail y demas
        $headers .= 'From: XXXXX <no_contestar@datoweb.com>' . "\r\n";
}
    
    // Enviar el Email
    if(mail($email,$subject,$htmlContent,$headers)){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
    
    // Estado de la salida del correo
    echo $status;die;
}
```

Alguien tiene una sugerencia? El error lo marca en la funcion mail();

Comment: ¿Qué hay en la línea 4278?

Comment: @Sal Es la linea del if($email,$subject,$htmlContent,$headers))

Comment: valida los parametros de "$email" puede que te este dando otra cosa que no sea un correo.

Comment: ¿Cómo se llama el archivo donde está tu función `email()`? El mensaje de error refiere a un archivo no encontrado, y suele ocurrir cuando usas `include` o `require`, no cuando pones un `if`, es extraño que ocurra ahí.

Comment: @A.Cedano lo extraño es que solo hago include al archivo DBConnection, pues solo se encarga de conectar a la BD

Comment: Falta contexto en tu pregunta. ¿En qué carpeta está el archivo que refieres y cómo se llama ese archivo? ¿Cuál es su ubicación con respecto al archivo actual (donde ocurre el error)? ¿Cuál es el código donde haces el `include` o el `require`?